# Set an option from the dropdown when page loads in jquery

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have the following html:

```
<select id="id_visit_number" name="visit_number">
  <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
```

When the page is opened / loaded, I want the default option to be selected as `Two`. So I tried the code below, but was not working

```
<script type='text/javascript">

        $( document ).ready(function() {
                $("select #id_visit_number option").filter(function() {
                    return $(this).val() == "2"; 
                }).prop('selected', true);
        });        
        </script>
```

How do I make an option selected by default when the page loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to give space. because that id in select dropdownlist

change

```
$("select #id_visit_number option")
```

to

```
$("select#id_visit_number option")
```

Comment: oh thats great, its really a simple mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Since IDs are supposed to be unique, you can always just write the ID without prefixing it with the element name and `$(this).val() == "2"` can also be written as `this.value == "2"`

```
   $("#id_visit_number option").filter(function() {
          return this.value == "2"; 
   }).prop('selected', true);
```

Please note that `("select #id_visit_number option")` is equivalent to:

```
    $("select").find("#id_visit_number").find("option");
    //clearly, that's not what you wanted.
```